¿Cómo traer el registro correcto de una tabla, dentro de un combo <SELECT>?
Tengo una tabla de bandas musicales con su CRUD correspondiente.  El campo "genereo" lo trae de otra tabla y lo muestra en un combo tipo <select>, y al momento de mostrar los datos para modificar, si bien trae el combo, no trae seleccionado el que tiene asignado, sino el último.
El código del combo es:
<!-- BODY -->

<?php 
$id=$_REQUEST["id"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bandas_solistas WHERE id='$id'";
$result = $conexion->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>

<form action="modificar_bys.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="modificar-bys">

    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">

    <label for="nombre_Banda">Nombre Banda/Solista:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nombre_Banda" name="nombre_Banda" value="<?php echo $row['nombre_Banda']?>" required><br><br>

    <label for="genero">Género:</label>
            <select type="text" name="genero" id="genero" size="4" required>             
              <?php
                $generos = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM generos ORDER BY genero");
                foreach ($generos as $opciones):
              ?>   
                <option value="<?php echo $opciones['id'] ?>" selected><?php echo $opciones['genero'] ?></option>                                      
              <?php endforeach ?>
            </select><br><br>
   
    <label for="desde">Desde:</label>
    <input type="text" id="desde" name="desde" value="<?php echo $row['desde']?>" required><br><br>

    
    <input type="submit" name="Modificar" value="Modificar Banda/Solista">
</form>

Estoy seguro de que el problema está en la etiqueta <select>; no sé dónde poner el selected.

En lugar de un foreach utilicé un while, de esta manera:
 <select type="text" name="genero" id="genero" required>             
            <?php
              $generos = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM generos ORDER BY genero");
              while ($opcion = mysqli_fetch_assoc($generos)):
                  $selected = ($opcion['id'] == $row['genero']) ? 'selected' : '';
              ?>   
                  <option value="<?php echo $opcion['id']; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $opcion['genero']; ?></option>                                      
              <?php endwhile; ?>
              
              <?php /*
                $generos = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM generos ORDER BY genero");
                foreach ($generos as $opciones):
              ?>   
                <option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $opciones['id'] ?>" ><?php echo $opciones['genero'] ?></option>                                      
              <?php endforeach */?>
            </select><br><br>


Pero el problema no ocurría a causa del forearch, sino porque no estabas haciendo esta comparación: $selected = ($opcion['id'] == $row['genero']) ? 'selected' : ''; en la cual verificas si el valor de $row['genero'] coincide con el de $opcion['id'] para entonces marcarlo como selected. Cuando usas el foreach no hacías esa comparación y por tanto todos se marcaban como selected, prevaleciendo finalmente el último, valga la redundancia.
